# how to pass a GUID to a select query of SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql, guid, sqldatasource

I have an SqlDataSource with following command:

```
SELECT * FROM [vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)
```

When I pass simple GUID like "3bd08871-d5d6-4f38-8c8a-29fd6077a719" as a UserId, then nothing gets selected. So what is the correct format for passing the GUID value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass a GUID value into an SqlCommand object SQL INSERT statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338038/how-do-i-pass-a-guid-value-into-an-sqlcommand-object-sql-insert-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change the parameter's type from Object to String:

```
  <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="UserID" QueryStringField="UserID" Type="String" />
```

Answer (score 1):

[How do I pass a GUID value into an SqlCommand object SQL INSERT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338038/how-do-i-pass-a-guid-value-into-an-sqlcommand-object-sql-insert-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the value in single quotes.